# Formal semantics of phrases like “I need to go to the store”

Tags: formal-semantics, modality, montague-grammar

Phrases like “I need to go to the store” do not express logical or contingent necessity. Possible words in which one does not go to the store feasibly exist. These phrases behave more as some kind of preference relation on a set of possible worlds. Is there much existing literature on these sorts of expressions?

Comment: I've read somewhere the opinion that most if not all uses of "need" are implicitly conditional on some assumption, such as "I need to go to the store if I'm going to have enough food for tomorrow". That condition is, though not explicitly pronounced, silently understood as part of the truth conditions, and the conditionalized sentence can then be adequately treated with the conventional semantics for the necessity operator. Can't remember the reference though.

Comment: I need to go to the store.= I have to go to the store. How is this anything but what it is?

Comment: Real language as used by people (as opposed to logicians) hardly ever has anything to do with logical necessity, and little to do with other formal logical operations. (eg _and_ and _or_ rarely mean the logical operators with those names).

Comment: @Lambie It's not anything else than "I have to go to the store", but it certainly is something else than logical necessity, which the question is about. It's not like the laws of the universe fall apart if I end up not going to the store and instead decide to stay at home and go without food tonight. Unlike something like "It is not the case that the keys are both on the table and not on the table" which *is* a logical necessity and can't be false in any conceivable world.

Comment: _Need_ is already a semi-modal in English, and has much the same deontic sense as _should_ or _must_. Any formal semantics that doesn't acknowledge its modality is missing the point, if not the whole boat

Comment: @lemontree That's not what "need" means, though. Language existed long, long, *long* before formal logic.

Comment: @cmw What is not what "need" means? And how does the fact that language existed before logic affect the question of how the word can be treated in the framework of possible world semantics?

Comment: Need != "must have or else the world will end".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point OP and I are making.

Comment: The question is: "must have or else the world will end" can not be what the word means, so how can we reconcile the two and analyze the sentence in the framework of possible world semantics, in a way that adequately accounts for its natural language meaning but hopefully still reveals some parallels to how we think of the concept of "necessity" in modal logic? That's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Are you aware of Kratzer’s work on modality (i.e. modal bases and ordering sources in formal semantics)?

Comment: Colin has hit the nail on the head. He's right. The language of logicians is not the same context as natural language per se.

Comment: @Lambie And noone claimed otherwise. You're pushing open doors.

Comment: @Keelan Yes, I'm actually supposed to read through that this weekend, and from the preliminary stuff, it seems as if it would apply here. Maybe some kind of modal bases and ordering in terms of preference, rather than probability. I.e. the worlds in which I do go to the store are more preferable to the ones in which I don't.